# Laravel authentication fails to the Hash result refreshing each time

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have made a Laravel Authentication system. It worked, but after updating laravel from 4.1.2.5 to 4.1.2.6 it stopped working. And I found out the problem, when the user tries to login, it fails since

`Auth::attemp(array("user"=>$username, "password"=>$password))`

regenrated the password Hashes and thus does not match against the one generated in time of registration.

Here is my User model:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    public function getAuthPassword(){

    }

    public function getAuthIdentifier(){

    }

    function getReminderEmail (){

    }

}
```

Here is my Login attempt:

```
Auth::attempt(array("email"=>$data['email'], 'password'=>$data['password']))
```

Comment: Are those 3 last methods really empty on your User model?

Answer (score 0):

There's a breaking change between 4.1.25 and 4.1.26. Please check the upgrade section [here](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26)